# How to convert data.frame column from Factor to numeric

Tags: r

I have a `data.frame` whose class column is `Factor`. I'd like to convert it to numeric so that I can use correlation matrix.

```
> str(breast)
'data.frame':   699 obs. of  10 variables:
 ....
 $ class                   : Factor w/ 2 levels "2","4": 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 ...
> table(breast$class)
  2   4 
458 241
> cor(breast)
Error in cor(breast) : 'x' must be numeric
```

How can I convert a Factor column to a numeric column?

Comment: This problem occurs too frequently to _not_ be a duplicate on SO

Comment: And the best answer is always the same, "read `?factor`"

Answer (score 112, accepted):

```
breast$class <- as.numeric(as.character(breast$class))
```

If you have many columns to convert to `numeric`

```
indx <- sapply(breast, is.factor)
breast[indx] <- lapply(breast[indx], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))
```

Another option is to use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` while reading the file using `read.table` or `read.csv`

Just in case, other options to create/change columns

```
 breast[,'class'] <- as.numeric(as.character(breast[,'class']))
```

or

```
 breast <- transform(breast, class=as.numeric(as.character(breast)))
```

Comment: If the case includes multiple column, what does "function(x)" in breast[indx] <- lapply(breast[indx], function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))) do?

Comment: @CouchTomato it is a lambda function or anonymous function ie. function created on the fly.  Here, the 'x' is each of the column values from the subset of columns `breast[indx]` looped in `lapply`.  `as.character` or `as.numeric` requires a input as vector and that is the reason we loop

Answer (score 15):

From `?factor`:

> To transform a factor f to approximately its original numeric values, `as.numeric(levels(f))[f]` is recommended and slightly more efficient than `as.numeric(as.character(f))`.

Answer (score 8):

This is [FAQ 7.10](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f).  Others have shown how to apply this to a single column in a data frame, or to multiple columns in a data frame.  But this is really treating the symptom, not curing the cause.

A better approach is to use the `colClasses` argument to `read.table` and related functions to tell R that the column should be numeric so that it never creates a factor and creates numeric.  This will put in `NA` for any values that do not convert to numeric.

Another better option is to figure out why R does not recognize the column as numeric (usually a non numeric character somewhere in that column) and fix the original data so that it is read in properly without needing to create `NA`s.

Best is a combination of the last 2, make sure the data is correct before reading it in and specify `colClasses` so R does not need to guess (this can speed up reading as well).

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to `$dollarsign` notation, use a `within` block:

```
breast <- within(breast, {
  class <- as.numeric(as.character(class))
})
```

Note that you want to convert your vector to a character before converting it to a numeric. Simply calling `as.numeric(class)` will not the ids corresponding to each factor level (1, 2) rather than the levels themselves.